# Is there any possibility to Call Flex Methods from Java?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, blazeds

I have the following Problem: I would like to Sync Data from a SQL Database into my Flex Datagrid. ATM im using Flex to call a Java Method. As long my Java Method is working i have to wait. So far so good.

Now, I want to rebuild that to the following Logic:
The Flex Application starts and does nothing. In the Background I want to start a Java Class who starts a Sync Method who is getting the Database Data every 5 seconds into a Arraylist. After getting the Data from the Java Class I want to cast from Java a Code like this:

```
myFlexClass.addItem(myList);
```

to set the DB Content into my Flex Frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call the java method from flex and coutinue to work. you will get back the control in flex to corresponding result handler , once the java method completes successfully.
(or)
you will get FaultEvent if there is any exception in the java method

check http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_6.html for more details

Comment: Thank you, but this is already working. My Problem is that i like to make a live sync every 5 Seconds between my Database and my Table. And the Content is very Big so it waste much Time until a user can work with the new Data. The claim is that is has to go through Java.

Comment: Upog i read the Article and it gave me the Information to dive in WebServices this should be the right way as far as i think :-) Thank you very very much u helped a lot.